# MPXJ library is interop based

Tags: ms-project, mpxj

I am using MPXJ library to access Microsoft Project file in .net. before proceeding with it i wanted to make sure either it is based on Microsoft Interop services or not.

i hope not :)

Comment: Microsoft Interop services means Microsoft Office API... which required JET engine and such ODBC drivers to access office based application using .net....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just to confirm, MPXJ is not based on any Microsoft APIs. It implements it own readers for the various file formats which it supports.

Hope that helps!

Jon

p.s. Disclaimer: I maintain MPXJ

Comment: Thanks, can we use MPXJ to access any other Microsoft Project alike application like Open Project based Projiti, Mac based iTaskx, KDE based KPLOTO.. or any other..? or any other library u know alike MPXJ for this purpose?

Comment: Hello Jon, Thanks for your response. Just wondering if we can schedule tasks start/finish dates using MPXJ.

like suppose i have added 3 tasks. task 1, task 2. task 3 and task 2 has dependency of finish to start and task 3 has dependency of finish to finish... how would their start/finish dates would be recalculated on the basis of dependencies i added?